# How to sink a for loop into pdf and txt file.

Tags: r, loops, pdf, sink

I am trying to run a for loop that sinks both a pdf and a text file into a seperate folder. The code I have looks like this.

```
library(MASS)
library(QuantPsyc)

rm(list=ls())

dat1<-read.csv("C:/Users/tmf/Desktop/Extract/Childsupdated_NewFiredata.csv")
stn<-unique(dat1$Station.x)
Sumdat<-as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=length(unique(stn)),ncol=18))
names(Sumdat)<-c("Lake Id","Intercept_Pvalue","Temp_Pvalue","Psum_Pvalue","PCT_Pvalue","DF","Multiple R2","Temp_VariableImp","Psum_VariableImp","Pct_VariableImp","Total_variableImp","ModelP_Value")

sink()
for (i in 1:length(stn)) {
  dat2<-dat1[dat1$Station.x==stn[i],]
  pdf(paste("C:/Users/tmf/Desktop/Extract/Outputs 17 Oct/PPT_Ha_Sum_100/",stn[i],".pdf",sep=""))
  sink(paste("C:/Users/tmf/Desktop/Extract/Outputs 17 Oct/PPT_Ha_Sum_100/",stn[i],".txt",sep=""))
  print(stn[i])
}
```

Unfortunately, the loop remains open at the end or results in a sink stack full error, I'm assuming it is a minor issue but I'm hoping someone can assist me in fixing the loop error or suggest a simpler way to loop and sink.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  The `pdf()` device is for graphics...  And you never close the `pdf()` device or call `sink()` again to close the diversion.  Try asking a question that is somewhat reproducible.  If you're just trying to split dat1 by station and output a delimited file, there are much easier ways.

Comment: Inside your loop, when you are finished writing to a particular file, you should run `sink()` to close the sink re-direct and `dev.off()` to close the open pdf graphics device. But as @oropendola mentioned, this is an odd way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented if you're just trying to output separate files for each 'Station.x', then you can adapt something like this:

```
data(iris)
lapply(split(iris, iris$Species), 
function(x) write.table(x, file = sprintf('%s.txt', unique(x$Species))))
```